# Wordpress: How to display users on a page

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

I'm new to this just so you guys know.
So I want to display all registered users on a template page.

what I have right now in my template is:

```
$member_type = (isset($member_type) ? $member_type : 'seb');
$post_type = $member_type == 'seb' ? array('companies', 'members') : 'companies';
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => $post_type,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'member_type',
            'value' => $member_type,
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

if ($member_type == 'seb') {
    $args['meta_query']['relation'] = 'OR';

    array_push( $args['meta_query'], array(
        'key' => 'company',
        'value' => '',
        'compare' => '='
    ) );
}


$users = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'ID' ) ) );
foreach($users as $user_id){
    print_r(get_user_meta ( $user_id->ID));
}
```

what I'm I doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You follow this link then you get users easily by using this function. I hope its beneficial for you.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_users/

> ```
> $blogusers = get_users( array( 'fields' => array( 'display_name' ) ) );
> // Array of stdClass objects.
> foreach ( $blogusers as $user ) {
>     echo '<span>' . esc_html( $user->display_name ) . '</span>';
> }
> ```